# I would like to code up an equation in R that calculates Ridge Regression Criteria

Tags: r, regression

The criteria is determined by the following function in the attached image. 
I have been working at it for a while now but this is what I have. I need to

```
ridge.crit <- function(y, X, lambda, beta){
n <- length(y) #number of rows
p <- ncol(X) #number of predictor variables
  for(i in 1:n){
    (y[i] - beta[1] - sum(beta[2:p+1] * X[i,]))^2
##WE GOTTA ADD THEM TOGETHER AND STORE FINAL ANSWER AND RETURN IT!
    }
  return(final_answer)
}
```

[image]

Comment: [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) can do this for you, if this is more of a practical exercise than a learning one

Comment: Yeah, no the point is to code up our own function here. I am unsure how to use the loop to sum the results of the first part and then add that to the last summand...